# Using UIDynamicAnimator on a scrollview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit-dynamics

I am trying to implement  `UIDynamicAnimator` effects on a `scrollView` with many elements. I couldn't find too much information about it anywhere ,so i just need some starting point.

So i have my `scrollView`, with many `UIViews` in it. i want to make any kind of animation to its "subViews" while scrolling.

Tried that-nothing happens .

```
  //DYNAMICS ANIMATIONS
    UIDynamicAnimator *dynamic=[[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:scroller];
    UIGravityBehavior *gravityBeahvior = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:mainCellsArray];
    [dynamic addBehavior:gravityBeahvior];
```

When `mainCellsArray` holds all the "subViews" of the scroller .

**EDIT**:
I have a strong `property` for the `dynamic` .
The array holds my costume classes pointers , that each class is a `UIView` subclass, and they all the scroller children's.

Comment: Thnanks both .I have a property for the UIDynamicAnimator *dynamic , but i still see nothing happens when scroll. i must say that the array holds my costume classes,that each one is a UIView subclass, is this right ?

Comment: You say "I still see nothing [happen] when [I] scroll". I don't follow you. Are you not seeing the views move at all? Or were you expecting to see them at the bottom when you scroll to the bottom? When you add the gravity behavior, the subviews will fall, and unless you add a collision behavior, they'll continue to fall well after they're no longer visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you define your animator as a property, not solely as a local variable (and I tend to use `animator` for the name of that, to avoid confusion with the `@dynamic` keyword):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIDynamicAnimator *animator;
```

Then instantiate the animator:

```
self.animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.scrollView];
```

And add the gravity:

```
UIGravityBehavior *gravityBehavior = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[viewToAnimate]];
[self.animator addBehavior:gravityBehavior];
```

If you want them to stop when they hit the bottom of the `contentSize` of the scroll view, you can't use the typical `translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary` setting. You have to make a path yourself, e.g. something like:

```
UICollisionBehavior *collision = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[viewToAnimate]];
CGRect contentSizeRect = {CGPointZero, self.scrollView.contentSize};
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:contentSizeRect];
[collision addBoundaryWithIdentifier:@"contentSize" forPath:path];
[self.animator addBehavior:collision];
```

Or, if you want them to fly off the scroll view, you probably want to remove them when they no longer intersect the `contentSize` of the scroll view:

```
UIGravityBehavior *gravity = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[viewToAnimate]];
UIGravityBehavior __weak *weakGravity = gravity;
CGRect contentSizeRect = {CGPointZero, self.scrollView.contentSize};
gravity.action = ^{
    if (!CGRectIntersectsRect(contentSizeRect, viewToAnimate.frame)) {
        NSLog(@"removing view");
        [viewToAnimate removeFromSuperview];
        [self.animator removeBehavior:weakGravity];
    }
};
[self.animator addBehavior:gravity];
```